# $PATH is different when using ssh vs using java

Tags: java, linux, ssh

When I ssh into a server, I can see that the PATH variable is set as required with some custom folders added required.

When I try to connect to the same server using com.jcraft.jsch.JSch library in Java, the PATH is set to something else.
`/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games`

This seems like a out of the box value and doesn't include the custom folders as required. None of the commands that I need to work when I connect through Java unless I give the full path to the executable. I need to connect to different servers and they might be set up with executables in different locations so this is not an option.

I was hoping someone could help me figure out why the ./bashrc file doesn't run when I connect using Java. Should I have to run it manually?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: I posted it here because it is about programming with Java. I am trying to use Java APIs to connect to ssh and it is not behaving the same way as it does when I use ssh to connect to it. I thought someone with Java experience might be able to help with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you connect using command-line SSH, your "default command" is whatever shell you have set up for your username on the remote machine (probably `bash`, which you can change with `chsh`), and then `bash` imports your `.bashrc` file.

When you connect using JSch, the type of `Channel` that you open will determine what will be done with your connection. From what I understand about how JSch works, chances are that JSch is not opening `bash` when it opens the SSH session.

As a general rule of thumb, try using `~/.ssh/environment` to set up your `PATH` instead of `.bashrc` if the SSH daemon is configured to allow it. This will always be imported before SSH runs any commands, including the shell, so it's more reliable for setting up your `PATH`.

More info can be found in [this Unix StackExchange post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/332532/how-to-set-path-when-running-a-ssh-command) about `.bashrc`, `PATH`, and SSH, including some alternatives to my answer.